# Is there a name for this operation on integer functions?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, integer-sequences

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are functions from $\mathbb N^+$ to itself.  I want to consider the function $f^g$, where $f^g(n) = f \circ \dots \circ f(n)$, where composition is done $g(n)$-many times. Note that if $f$ and $g$ are monotonic increasing then so is $f^g$.  Is there a name for this operation, or something similar?

Comment: That would be $n\mapsto(\ulcorner g(n) \urcorner\, f) (n)$, where $\ulcorner m \urcorner$ is the [Church numeral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals) for $m$.